# "empty data message" in renderTable

Tags: r, shiny

I user renderTable to show some data. However, sometimes the data table is empty, in which case I'd like to print "No data to show" or something similar. the default by renderTable is to show nothing for empty data. can this be changed? how?

Comment: With an `if` statement and a `message`

Comment: probably not that simple. if my ui contains a tableOutput(), then it expects a table (a result of renderTable, or something similar). Trying to assign a character message to that ui element results in an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a condition into a `renderUi` to render either a message or a "tableOutput" (you can't render directly the table)

```
datas <- data.frame()

shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", choices = c("iris", "datas"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("ui")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset,
             "iris" = iris,
             "datas" = datas)
    })

    output$ui <- renderUI({
      if(nrow(datasetInput()) == 0)
        return("No data to show")

      tableOutput("table")
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
      head(datasetInput())
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: thanks. I suspected that this would involve a renderUI, which requires more "programming", and kind of hurt the nice separation between ui and logic. Ideally I would like that the renderTable will have an additional parameter that adds flexibility in terms of what need to be done when there is no data to show. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for something like [validate](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) function.

Using example code provided by Julien:

```
    datas <- data.frame()

    shiny::runApp(list(

      ui = pageWithSidebar(

        headerPanel("Example"),

        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", choices = c("iris", "datas"))
        ),

        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('table')
        )
      ),

      server = function(input, output, session) {

        datasetInput <- reactive({
          switch(input$dataset,
                 "iris" = iris,
                 "datas" = datas)
        })


        output$table <- renderTable({
          y <- head(datasetInput())
                validate(
                  need(nrow(y) > 0, "No Data to show")
                         )
        y
        })

      }

    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to show a "table" within the UI, do this:

```
output$table_output <- renderTable {
    data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), 
                       b = c(8,9)) #example data.frame
    if (nrow(data) > 0) { 
      data 
    } else {
      datatable(data.frame(Nachricht = "Die ausgewählte Schnittstelle enthält hierfür keine Daten."))
    }
}
```

[image]