# R shiny output 0 record table show 'no record'

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app having a table output. 
I want to let the UI showing 'No record' when there are is no record in the table.

any suggestion?

you can change this code for demo:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("INFOMATION CHECKING TOOL"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  mainPanel(


    h4("Records Sepal.Length bigger than 7.9", align = "center"),
    tableOutput("table"),
    br(),
    br()

  )
)  

# define server() function
server <- function(input, output){


  output$table <- renderTable({


    iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>7.9)

  })

}

# call to shinyApp() which returns the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How about using `validate` as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43934495/3460670

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the info. it seems not right. Validate is validating the input dataset is empty or not. My input is right but just due to a 'filter' the output is empty. If use same thing in R markdown, I will see '0 rows'. I want to show same '0 rows' in shiny.

Comment: Did you review @bretauv's answer? Did you try it? If this doesn't meet your needs, please clarify your question further to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Ben said, you can use validate on dataframes too, not only on inputs.

```
output$table <- renderTable({

    data_test <- iris %>% 
      filter(Sepal.Length>7.9)

    validate(
      need(nrow(data_test) > 0,
           "No record"
      )
    )

    data_test

  })
```

See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) to customize the `validate` message (font, color, etc.).